# Django and docker, ImportError: Could not import settings '"config"' Is it on sys.path?

Tags: python, django

I'm step by step switching my django project to work on local from vagrant to docker.

With docker, you don't need a virtualenv. 
Even if I find it very convenient I'm facing some new troublesome issues.

The main one is this error on ./manage.py cmd:

> ImportError: Could not import settings '"config"' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named '"config"'

So when I start the python console code and type:

```
>> import sys
>> sys.path
>> ['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

But my path project is:
`/var/www/webapps/wrapper_website/app`

I've a setup environment loaded on docker-compose up which contain:
`DJANGO_CONFIGURATION="LocalContent"`

And that's what I'm trying to reach. 
The config folder is in:
`/var/www/webapps/wrapper_website/app/config`

I've tried this in the wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Production")
sys.path.insert(0, 
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))) <- this line
from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Without success.

Comment: Your `WORKDIR` in Dockerfile should be `/var/www/webapps/wrapper_website/app/` Can you check that?

Comment: It stops one folder before, `WORKDIR /var/www/webapps/wrapper_website`

Comment: So, Workdir should be you project root directory, where `manage.py`, application folders and etc are located.

Comment: Modifying the workdir doesn't change the error on a ./manage.py command